# How to display an image from SD card on Android canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, image

I would like to load a picture from SD card and display it on the canvas. I have a list of pictures and I want to diplay the picture selected by the user. Probably I have to use canvas.drawBitmap or canvas.drawPicture functions, but I don't know how. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Try them, perhaps it's easier than you think. 2. There is a `ImageView`-class for a reason. 3. Google first, ask later.

Comment: To help with your understanding, you don't display anything on a `Canvas`.  A `Canvas` is nothing more than a holder for drawing calls to a bitmap, e.g. the image in an `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your :

```
        void draw(Canvas c) {
                    c.save();
                    c.drawColor(0xff000000);
                    doDraw(c); //method to call to set the image  
            }

 public void doDraw(Canvas c) {

    Resources res = getResources();
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.yourimage);
    c.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);
 }
```